# Using Hardware pwm as event timer?

Tags: pwm, real-time

in modern PC based Linux Machines it is possible to use hpet and realtime processes to get a reasonable good realtime performance (+-10us response time)

While Raspberry Pi Hardware does not have a hpet device, it does have Hardware PWM.

Thus it would likely be possible to use the Hardware PWN as a Realtime source by connecting its output to another interrupt driven GPIO input.

I was now wondering if this connection could also be done by Software using a device tree overwrite.

Comment: For what purpose?  Are you just using the PWM signal as a clock?  It won't magically makes the system real time or respond any faster.  You need to explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I try to solve the problem that Raspberry Pi does not have a clock source like hpet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer). I thought I made this clear enough.

Comment: I think this is an example of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I do not think this is the case. I am explicitly looking for an _alternative_ solution to my x86 only stuff (hpet+realtime process).

Comment: PWM may provide an alternative to hpet.  It does not help with the realtime process part.  Good luck with your task.

Comment: Are you sure the RPi doesn't have a high-resolution timer? Can you post the contents of `/proc/timer_list`? [This guy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8586/arm-timer-in-kernel-module-with-precision-less-than-microsecond) seems to have a working HR timer.

Comment: There is neither a "Clock Event Device" of type hpet listed in /proc/timer_list nor does a /dev/hpet inode exist. So at least when using the standard Raspbian kernel there ist no hpet device.