# HIgh resolution timer?

Tags: real-time, timekeeping

Is any high resolution timer available on a Raspberry Pi that can be used by an application (for micro-benchmarking, etc.) without having to write a kernel driver?

The resolution I'm looking for is sub-millisecond or microseconds, but microseconds or nanoseconds are preferred. For timing compiled C vs. ARM assembly language code. Added jitter to ameliorate Spectre is OK.

Comment: depends on the OS

Comment: current default install of Raspbian Stretch or Stretch-lite from raspberrypi.org

Comment: This is a bit vague.  What do you call high resolution?  What do you plan to time and how?

Comment: Sub-millisecond or microseconds. But microseconds or nanoseconds preferred.  For timing compiled C vs. ARM assembly language code.  Added jitter to ameliorate Spectre is OK.

Comment: @hotpaw2 You should add clarifications to your question rather than in comments.

Comment: Take a look at Boost Chrono Class (https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.chrono)

Comment: Related: [Arm timer in kernel module with precision less than microsecond](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8586/arm-timer-in-kernel-module-with-precision-less-than-microsecond)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to check for high-resolution timer support by installing the `rt-tests` package and running `cyclictest` with the period that you're interested in. For [example](https://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers)

```
cyclictest -n -p 80 -i 500 -l 5000
```

> This does a test of `clock_nanosleep()`, with priority 80, at 500 microsecond intervals, running the 5000 iterations of the test.

According to a brief [search](https://projects.drogon.net/accurate-delays-on-the-raspberry-pi/), **`nanosleep()` is supported in Raspbian**.

Another source of useful information about available timers is `/proc/timer_list`.